# Error Android Studio: error: unknown element <service> found

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-messaging

Buen dia 
Tengo el siguiente error con los servicios de google en firebase Android Studio

```
error: unknown element <service> found.
```

Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: unknown element  found., sources=[C:\Users\Sony Vaio\Desktop\Backup_20_10_18\09_08_18\DiabetesApp_new\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:20], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el manifest tengo este error tambien 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y Tengo estructurado asi el manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.firebase"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <service android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.github.hathibelagal.pn.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> <!-- Optional permission for App measurement to run. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcherb"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.SignupActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.ResetPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_reset_password"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.Calculate"
            android:parentActivityName="info.androidhive.firebase.MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.Hipoglucemia"
            android:parentActivityName="info.androidhive.firebase.MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.Hitorial"
            android:parentActivityName="info.androidhive.firebase.MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.Hitorial2" />
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.History"
            android:parentActivityName="info.androidhive.firebase.MainActivity" />
        <!--
         FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="info.androidhive.firebase" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!--
 Internal (not exported) receiver used by the app to start its own exported services
             without risk of being spoofed.
        -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
            android:exported="false" />
        <!--
 FirebaseInstanceIdService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:authorities="info.androidhive.firebase.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
            android:authorities="info.androidhive.firebase.com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
            android:multiprocess="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Y tengo la siguiente estrutura en build.Gradle(app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.androidhive.firebase"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar por favor

Comment: click en Build->Rebuild Project

Comment: Listo amigo ya realizo eso

Comment: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Comment: aparece eso luego de realizar las acciones

Comment: Me aparece este mensaje en la cabezera de la pantalla 
files under the folder are generated and should not be edited

Comment: Que quiere decir Los archivos debajo de la carpeta se generan y no deben editarse.

Comment: en que pantalla?

Comment: En la parte superior del codigo donde aparece tambien el mensaje de syn como notificacion

Comment: pero basicamente es esto

Comment: error: unknown element <service> found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: unknown element <service> found., sources

Comment: Lo que sale en Debug

Comment: @Julian  estas definiendo un elemento <service> a nivel de los permisos, lo cual no es valido, es el que señalo en mi respuesta, debes colocarlo dentro de <application. Por cierto Build->Rebuild Project no funciona si existe algún problema en los recursos o configuración.

Answer (score 1):

Tu manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<service android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<uses-permission android:name="com.github.hathibelagal.pn.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> <!-- Optional permission for App measurement to run. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcherb"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:testOnly="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.SignupActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.ResetPasswordActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reset_password"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.Calculate"
        android:parentActivityName="info.androidhive.firebase.MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.Hipoglucemia"
        android:parentActivityName="info.androidhive.firebase.MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.Hitorial"
        android:parentActivityName="info.androidhive.firebase.MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.Hitorial2" />
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.History"
        android:parentActivityName="info.androidhive.firebase.MainActivity" />
    <!--
     FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
         no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
    -->
    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="info.androidhive.firebase" />
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
        android:exported="false" />

    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <provider
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:authorities="info.androidhive.firebase.firebaseinitprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:initOrder="100" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
        android:authorities="info.androidhive.firebase.com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
        android:multiprocess="true" />
</application>
```

Comment: Lo corrijo y coloco ese?

Comment: prueba solo he bajo el service dentro de aplication

Comment: Ya lo probe me sigue saliendo igual amigo

Comment: :( que sera amigo

Comment: prueba ahora con el manifest que te puse lo he editado ya que habia una etiquta no cerrada

Comment: Listo amigo, voy a revisar tu edicion ya te comento como me fue

Comment: No amigo sigue igual :(

Answer (score 0):

El error:

> error: unknown element  found.

en tu caso indica que en realidad estas definiendo el siguiente elemento `<service>` a nivel de los permisos, lo cual no es valido :

```
...
...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <service android:name="info.androidhive.firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.github.hathibelagal.pn.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
...
...
```

debes definirlo dentro de `<application` ya que la definición de servicios debe definirse siempre dentro de la etiqueta `<application>`.

Revisa [Manifiesto de la app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro)

---

Por cierto veo que también estas usando dentro de tu archivo `Build.gradle` para definir las dependencias `compile` :

```
dependencies {
       compile '...'
       testCompile '...'
       compile '...'
       compile '...'
}
```

debes cambiar a usar ahora `implementation` :

```
dependencies {
       implementation '...'
       testImplementation '...'
       implementation '...'
       implementation '...'
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo voy a revisar tus sugerencias y te cuento en momentos

Comment: Jorge, lo agrege en aplication y revise las dependencias y no amigo sigue igual